# Ghosting occurs when using inkscape to insert a pdf_tex into tex

Tags: xetex, inkscape

I use inkscape to make vectorgraph and insert into tex by pdf_tex,the font is a little big when I choose `Omit text in pdf and create LaTeX file` of `Text output options`

[image]

But there is ghosting when I choose `Embed fonts`or`Covert text to paths`
[image]

This is my tex code

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \input{SM_Join.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

I know i could use `\scriptsize` but I want to know  how to resolve this problem.

Comment: The pdf_tex export produces two files: a .pdf and a .pdf_tex file. The .pdf_tex file includes the .pdf file internally and puts any text on top as LaTeX code. If you later export as 'regular' pdf with text included then this will overwrite the original pdf that was intended to be used together with the pdf_tex file, and the text is added twice (once by the old pdf_tex and once by the new pdf). If you want text as curved or embedded then you should use `\includegraphics{SM_join}` instead of `\input{SM_Join.pdf_tex}`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the reason. But`\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}`does not work for `\includegraphics{SM_join}` . I'll just use `\scriptsize`

Comment: For that you can use `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{SM_join}`.